# Where does the measure/metric in a fact table come from?

Tags: database, data-modeling, data-warehouse, fact-table

I am new to the concept of a data warehouse and was a bit confused about the fact table. I am designing a data warehouse for a university system and have a fact table that can populate a transcript. I have foreign keys in the fact table linking to dimensions STUDENT, COURSE, DEGREE. As for the measure/metric of the fact table, I am using grade and semester for the unit of time. My question is, should the metric (in this case the grade) be loaded into the fact table manually, or should it be loaded into the fact table from some table in the source database like the dimensions? Thank you in advance.

**EDIT**: Sorry if the question is a bit unclear. Basically what I'm asking is given any fact table, is the measure of the fact table allowed to be retrieved from a source database, or does it have to be entered manually into the data warehouse.

Comment: it's unclear what you are asking. If you already have data in the source database, why would you want to enter it manually? It makes no sense.

Comment: @RADO the values of the fact table student_id, course_id and degree_id are all loaded into the warehouse from the source databases. But where i am unclear is whether or not the measure of a fact table (grade attribute in this case) is should be retrieved from the source database as well.

Comment: I guess I am missing something... Data warehouse is a copy of source data, cleaned up and optimized for reporting. Why would you want to manually enter any data if you already have it in the source systems? Is there anything special about importing fact table data vs dimensional data? Why should it be treated differently?

Comment: Data in a data warehouse has to come from somewhere. Most data warehouses are agglomerations of data from other systems (feeds) which are transactional. It is highly unlikely that users will be manually entering data into a data warehouse. So yes, you should be taking the measures from your source system along with the dimensions.